# Oauth social login using MEAN.js Restful sessionless API backend

Tags: angularjs, oauth, restful-authentication, meanjs

I'm developing a Restful API using MEAN.js, which will be consumed by an AngularJS Web site and Phonegap Mobile Apps.

I'd like the user to be able to create an account and/or login using Faceboo, Google and Twitter.

I'm trying to use the same sample code that comes with MEAN.js seed application, but with the Node side of it, on port 3000 serving only the API, and the web site running on another server (currently on port 9000).

I','ve already implemented Token authentication using a Passport custom Local strategy, which generates a token, and the Bearer Strategy to autheticate API calls.

But I'm having problems with social login, to link social accounts to existing users.

From the Angular Client I call an api endpoint that redirects the user to the oauth provider (e.g. Twitter). When the user comes back, my serve has no knowledge of the logged user, since I'm not using sessions anymore.

I've tried to return the provider token to the client, but have problems parsing the anguler url. Then I coded another page outside angular that receives the provider token and calls an api endpoint sending the oauth token and the token issued by my api. It worked for Google, but not for Twitter. It seems twitter needs a session.

Anyway, what is the best approach to achieve what I want? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Since your using Angularjs, take a look at this Angularjs library https://github.com/sahat/satellizer. The library pretty much opens up an oauth popup and checks the popup url for tokens. You can easily replicate the approach or just use this library. It works with a few social media providers like Twitter and its easy to add more.

Answer (score 0):

I was in need of the same thing and so I set out to create my own. It's still in development but should give you a good start. Feel free to create a pull request and help to make it better. Maybe we can eventually merge it into their codebase.

https://github.com/elliottross23/MeanJsSocialLoginTokenAuth